# Rails3 activerecord update_attributes can't save foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

In rails 3.0.9/ruby 1.9.2 I'm getting unexpected behaviour when i try to update model foreign keys.

I start with a fresh install

```
$ rails new mytest
$ rails g model User 
$ rails g model Ad user_id:integer
$ rake db_migrate
```

Add association in app/models/Ad.rb

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now to the fun part. I want to change the foreign key on an object directly. I enter rails console with **rails c**

```
$ u = User.create
$ a=Ad.create(:user=>u)
$ a.update_attributes(:user_id => 9999)
$ a.user_id
=> 4
```

So that doesn't work. I try to set the object directly instead of passing it to create:

```
$ u = User.create
$ a=Ad.create
$ a.user = u
$ a.save
$ a.update_attributes(:user_id => 9999)
$ a.user_id
=> 5
```

Doesn't work.

The only thing that works is this:

```
$ u = User.create
$ a=Ad.create
$ a.user_id = u.id
$ a.save
$ a.update_attributes(:user_id => 9999)
$ a.user_id
=> 9999
```

Can someone please explain what is going on, and how can I change the foreign keys of my objects? I assume the "blocking" behaviour happens when the objects associations are instantiated and there is a conflict, so one answer is to do this:

```
$ Ad.find( a.id ).update_attributes( :user_id => xxxx )
```

That works. But it seems like a long way to go just for changing a foreign key on an object. It also takes an extra DB hit, and lastly it is quite messy code if an object internally needs to update itself. What to do?

Comment: Btw: The reason i ran into this problem is that i switched from Machinist to FactoryGirl. Machinist doesn't load associated objects on creation, but FactoryGirl does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just unload the loaded object before doing the update

```
a = Ad.create( :user=>User.create )
a.user.reset   # Unload association object, the foreign key is untouched
a.update_attributes( :user_id=>9999 )
a.user_id
  => 9999
```

You can make Factory girl create objects with unloaded associations like this

```
def Factory.lazy( model )
    obj = Factory( model )
    obj.attributes.each{ |k,v|
    if assoc = k[/(.*)_id$/,1]
        eager = obj.send( assoc )
        eager.send("reset") unless eager.nil?
    end
    obj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the proper explanation requires me to check the source code of Rails and check what it is happening with `update_attributes` when you assign an object to the relationship. I will check that later.

But I guess the correct thing to do is not just update the attribute, but the whole user object. Something like:

```
u = User.create; a = Ad.create; a.user = u; a.save; a.user = User.find(9999); a.save
```

Or just manipulate the ids of your object like you noticed it worked:

```
u = User.create; a = Ad.create; a.user_id = u.id; a.save; a.user_id = 9999; a.save
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue you're experiencing is because you're trying to change the user_id attribute directly. Because you've added `belongs_to :user` to the Ad model, Rails has a number of additional methods to help deal with the association. Here's the page from the rails guides on the `belongs_to` methods: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference

In this case you can use something like this:

```
u1 = User.create
u2 = User.create
a=Ad.create(:user=>u)
```

`a.user_id` will equal `u1.id`

To update the association, you can do this:

```
a.user = u2
a.save!
```

and now `a.user_id` should equal `u2.id`

Rails is doing this because it assumes that the association is more than just a foreign key as the `User` object is more important than the backend foreign key.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I found a third workaround, which I believe is the best because I don't want to make that extra DB hit and change the code to fit into the test suite im using - it should be the other way around. The situation is that I have an object with associations and I want to copy it to another object it via JSON. This works flawlessly in rails but Factory Girl (test fixture generator) creates eager loaded object associations. See next answer.

Comment: You can have Factory Girl build objects without hitting the database as well. So, in your case Factory.build(:object), rather than Factory.create(:object)

Comment: Well, without getting into too deep explanations Factory.build(:object) doesn't work for my purpose, I need objects that are persisted in the DB but without the loaded association (build() doesn't do that) and plain Factory() loads EVERYTHING into the object. See my answer for what to do - haven't been able to reply to my own question for 8 hours :-)